# Showing that the natural scale function is a martingale under specific conditions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

My question is related to this post [How to find the "natural scale function" for more general stochastic processes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391105/how-to-find-the-natural-scale-function-for-more-general-stochastic-processes). Indeed, I am trying to solve an exercise in which I have to show that if the function $\mu$ is positive on $[0,+\infty[$ and negative on $]-\infty,0[$, then the local martingale defined by $S(X_t)$ is in fact a martingale.
I used Ito formula and came to the conclusion that I had to show that $\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{t}|S'(X_s)\sigma(X_s)|^2ds]$ is finite. But I do not see how to use the assumption given on $\mu$...

Thank you for your help.